# Excel VBA: List of changes

Tags: excel, vba

In Excel I can activate "Track changes while editing." with "Select "Highlight changes on screen.", and I get all changes visible.

Now I want to generate a complex report of all these changes, so I need a way to access this information via VBA. Unfortunatly there is no "Workbook.Changes" Property.

Does anybody know how to do it?

Kind regards,
Thomas

Comment: Found some code to create your own track changes: [http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=909][1] which seems simple enough. SO I guess you could use this to log the changes yourself and create your own Workbook.Changes alternative.

Comment: There is no built-in way to do this, so as Dan notes you'll need to code it (and there are several good examples out there).  Note however that a "bullet-proof" method is very tricky to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you need to track changes for, you might be able to use [Spreadsheet Compare](http://www.thefoolonthehill.net/drupal/Spreadsheet%20Compare/) to help report on changes. It's an Excel Addin with lots of options for reporting on the differences between 2 workbook.

If you save a copy of the workbook before editing it, you could use this tool to summarize the differences after edits.

Answer (score 0):

Did you notice that there is a built in option that allows you to 'List changes on a new sheet' ?
*The best macro is no macro. (old Excel proverb)*